# Efficient algorithm to compute pairwise inequality matrix

Tags: algorithms

> Given an array of integers $(a_1,\ldots,a_N)$, what is an *efficient* method to compute the matrix $A\in\mathbb{Z}_2^{N\times N}$ whose $(i,j)$ entry is $1$ if $a_i < a_j$, and $0$ otherwise?

By *efficient* I mean something better than comparing all elements pairwise, which requires $O(N^2)$ comparisons.

---

**CONTEXT**

I am aware that the brevity of the question may make it unclear. I will try to clarify with an example. To *sort* an array of length $N$ one may use $O(N^2)$ comparisons, but it's quite a shocking fact that we can do it with much less: $O(N\log N)$. Intuitively, only $O(N\log N)$ comparisons are necessary to completely determine all the relations among the array.

Now, what I am asking here is whether a similar thing holds for the comparison matrix. Can we compute, say $O(N\log N)$ comparisons, and from these infer all the entries from the comparison matrix? Again, just like in the sorting case, we can compute all these $N^2$ entries separately using one comparison for each, but can we do better?

Comment: I guess you don't want us to reorder the array, and then create the matrix for that reordered array?

Comment: @Sudix Thanks for the comment. Isn't the matrix for the reordered array trivial?

Comment: It is, but that is the first step I would do if I'd try to optimize. If you want the matrix to be fixed, that would force me to throw permutation matrices on it afterwards, which most likely would put us in $O(N^2)$ again anyway.

Comment: @Daniel What do mean by "compute"? For an already ordered/reordered array, the matrix will be upper triangle with zero diagonal and $1$'s in the triangular part. Such a matrix has $\frac{N(N - 1)}{2}$ i.e. $O(N^2)$ non-zero entries. So computing only the non-zero entries is still an $O(N^2)$ operation even in this best case scenario of an ordered array.

Comment: @ZeroXLR I apologize for the lack of clarity. I tried to make it clearer, please let me know if it makes sense.

Comment: what's exactly the definition of complexity here? the number of elements of $A$ you check? or the time complexity of the algorithm, these are two different things

Comment: @Daniel The problem is, that creating the matrix itself is already too much work for anything else to matter. Unless you accept that the matrix representation isn't really what you want, but more like a guarantee ,e.g. "I can check for all $\alpha_i,\alpha_j$ whether  $\alpha_i<\alpha_j$ in constant time", to get anywhere we'll have to drop the Oh-notation, as we'll not get below $O(N^2)$ I fear

Comment: @Sudix Thanks again! I get what you mean, but I honestly think there could be ways in which we can get something better than naively comparing the elements in a pairwise manner. As you noted, for instance, if the array is sorted then the comparison matrix is trivial. Furthemore, the matrix satisfies $a_{ij}\cdot a_{jk} \leq a_{ik}$, so maybe these properties imply that the matrix can be 'completed' by computing only $o(N^2)$ of its entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you seek to represent $A$. If you represent $A$ by storing only the index pairs $(i, j)$ where $A_{ij} = 1 \neq 0$, you cannot do better than $O(N^2)$.

For any such pair $(i, j)$, either $a_i < a_j$ or $a_i \geq a_j$ by trichotomy. So unless $i = j$, either you have to store $(i, j)$ or you have to store $(j, i)$. Thus, you are guaranteed to do
$$
\Big(\sum_{k = 1}^N k \Big) - N = \frac{N(N - 1)}{2} \sim O(N^2)
$$ storing operations just to instantiate $A$.

However, if you seek to represent $A$ as an algorithm that answers the following question:

> For a certain index $(i, j)$ is $A_{ij} = 1$ or is $A_{ij} = 0$?

Then it is trivial: if $a_i < a_j$, you output $1$ and $0$ otherwise.